# plpgsql associative array argumnent

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I once read this entry in mailing list http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2005-06/msg01481.php

```
SELECT *
FROM foo_func(
    c => current_timestamp::timestamp with time zone,
    a => 2,
    b => 5
);
```

Now I need this kindof solution where I can pass associative array argument to a function.
Do I need to make a dummy table and then use that table as argument type ? or there is any straight forward fix for this ? or has this hack been implemented ?

or can I emulate the same using pl/python ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass hstore values into the function?  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html

Comment: Hmm nice option But I am getting `ERROR: type "hstore" does not exist` I am using 8.4

Comment: Ah, I think it was just a contrib module back then.  Should work if you install it though.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/hstore.html

Comment: Well I checked in `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions` but it says `no such relation pg_available_extensions` can you tell me how can I install it or check it whether its installed or not ?

Comment: The extensions are a 9.1+ feature. I've put detailed instructions for 8.4 with code sample in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps for an answer with hstore and PG-8.4 for debian.

1) if not installed already, install the contrib package

```
# apt-get install postgresql-contrib-8.4
```

2) install hstore in the relevant database

```
$ psql -U postgres -d dbname
# \i /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/hstore.sql
```

2bis) If the plpgsql language is not installed, install it (still inside psql as postgres user)

```
# CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

3) create the function taking hstore as input. Here's an example in plpgsql that just enumerates the keys and values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function enum_hstore(in_h hstore) returns void
as $$
declare
  kv record;
begin
  for kv in select * from (select (each(in_h)).*) as f(k,v) loop
    raise notice 'key=%,value=%',kv.k,kv.v;
  end loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

4) call the function. Since the keys and values are of type text, it may be necessary to cast to text the non-literal entries, as the current_timestamp call in the question. Example:

```
  select enum_hstore(
    hstore('c',current_timestamp::text) ||
    'a=>2,b=>5'::hstore
  );
```

The result to expect from the above function:

```
 NOTICE:  key=a,value=2
 NOTICE:  key=b,value=5
 NOTICE:  key=c,value=2012-04-08 16:12:59.410056+02
```

Comment: Getting: Language `plpgsql` does not exist on step 3

Comment: Then step #2 should have the additional SQL command: `CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql`

Comment: Now I got a big error. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 2: CREATE OR REPLACE function enum_hstore(in_h hstore) returns ...` Side note: If I try with `language sql` I get `syntax error at or near "record"`

Comment: I can't see where the syntax error would be. It works for me. As for the sql language, it's not an option here, procedural code is wanted.

Comment: Do I need to do anything else like setting an handler for langage plpgsql ? or I missed something ?

Comment: I've done `sudo -u postgres createlang -I wee` and `sudo -u postgres createlang -l DBNAME` is showing ` plpgsql | yes` But still I am getting that error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE" LINE 2: CREATE OR REPLACE function enum_hstore(in_h hstore) returns ..` Side Note: However I am not seeing `plpgsql` in the pgAdmin III dialog. while creating a new function in its GUI

Comment: `select lanname from pg_language` will tell what languages are available. Since you're using pgadmin3, I have a theory that'd explain the error. I guess you're copying the CREATE... statement somewhere into pgadmin3 in a textarea where it expects only the body of the function and not the entire declaration. I'd suggest you temporarily forget about pgadmin3 and try with the `psql` command-line tool which is less complicated in this context.

Comment: `select lanname from pg_language` is giving `plpgsql` and I am entering the `CREATE` statement in psql not in textarea of pgadmin3. and now I am getting `plpgsql` in pgadmin3 also. after restarting pgadmin3. But the error persists. and I can create the function in pgAdmin3 But not in psql. Wired !!

Comment: :) I don't know how it all fixed. now its working even from psql too. Thanks. But I cant figure out what actually happened.One more question. installing that script has created a lot of functions in my database. which will mess up with my own functions. Now how can I seperate them ?

Answer (score 2):

This is implemented in [version 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/release-9-0.html):

> 4.3.2. Using named notation
>
> In named notation, each argument's name is specified using := to
>   separate it from the argument expression. For example:

```
SELECT concat_lower_or_upper(a := 'Hello', b := 'World');
 concat_lower_or_upper 
-----------------------
 hello world
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks but I am running 8.4 would I get 9.0 in stable debian release ? and how can I handle these key, value pair in function ?

Comment: But the names a and b have to be the names of the parameters inside the function, don't they?  I'm not sure but I think Neel's question wants to pass an arbitrary associative array to the function (I could be wrong though).

Comment: yes I need to pass arbitrary associative array not parameters. I am sorry if my question leads to a different meaning